# Edit and add. Contents of a JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json

So i have found a few previous topics on how to do this but none of them really made sense to me. I was wondering if someone could explain how to edit and add to the following:

```
{
  "users": {
    "account1": {
      "name": "username1",
      "id": "user1id",
      "shown": "do show"
    },
    "acount2": {
      "name": "username2",
      "id": "userd2id",
      "shown": "do show"
    },
  },
  "selectedAccount": "account1",
```

I wish to add a new account like accounts 1 and 2.
I also wish to change the selectedAccount's value.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

So i'm still needing help with this, this is what i am currently doing:

```
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        JSONObject profiles = jsonObj.getJSONObject("users");

        JSONObject jsonAttribute = new JSONObject();
        jsonAttribute.put("name", "username0");
        jsonAttribute.put("id", "user0id");
        jsonAttribute.put("shown", "do show");

        JSONObject newProfile = profiles.append(name, jsonAttribute);

        profiles.append("account0", newProfile);
```

Comment: Please show your code.  What have you tried so  far?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to start with this, if anyone could provide some assistance that'd be great.

Comment: Start with a good parsor like jackson, gson etc.  Create a suitable object model and load the data into it.  Then make modify the data as you need.  Save it back using library (again jackson. etc)